# ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$ regular Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

The above expression is working fine. this expression means first leter should start with characters only not a digit, remaining letters alphanumarics. but it not allow when i give underscore like "s_sasi" it is giving error message can u help me i want to allow the underscore also in that expression thank u

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

or better

```
^[A-Za-z][\w]*$
```

Comment: Hi Martin Hohenberg the expression is not accetping in the regular expression it is giving error thank you for response

Comment: @Surya - make sure you escape the \ sign: try ^[A-Za-z][\\w]*$, or `@"^[A-Za-z][\w]*$"`

Comment: `[\w]` is redundant : use `^[a-zA-Z]\w*$`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `^[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*$` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with ^[A-Za-Z](.*)
Inputs can be anything starting with an Alphabet.

you can use this site http://www.regexplanet.com/ for verifying your regular expressions
[regex](/questions/tagged/regex)